# Libgdx "затухающая" анимация

Tags: java, libgdx

Имеется кнопка `TextButton` , так же есть анимация `spinAnimation`.Ни как не могу понять, как реализовать "затухание анимации"(т.е. при нажатии на кнопку, анимация стартовала, и постепенно, через определенное время останавливалась). Пример Кода:

```
@Override
public void create(){

textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas("pack.atlas"); 
stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
sb = new SpriteBatch();

 final TextButton button = new TextButton("Start",skin , "default");
        button.setWidth(220);
        button.setHeight(50);


  button.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                spinAnimation.setFrameDuration(0.5f);
                int i = 0;


            }
        });

    stage.addActor(button);



           Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

@Override
   public void render() {

   elepsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
   Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);       
   Gdx.gl.glClear(com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   sb.begin();
   stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
   sb.draw(spinAnimation.getKeyFrame(elepsedTime,true), 50,  60


   sb.end();
   stage.draw();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто можно добавить в `ClickListner`

```
Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        spinAnimation.setFrameDuration(0f);


                    }

                },1);
```